# Constrained Lagrangian simulation. Fails depending on constraint definition

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, simulations, constrained-dynamics

## Introduction

I want to simulate a robotic leg that has a closed kinematic chain. The analytical equation i derived are compared with a simulink multibody model.

Initially, my simulation failed, and the inital question was about my formulation of the constraints (which was indeed wrong). I managed to successfully simulate the model, and **i want to understand why my initial method fails**.

I first describe my first attempt, which fails. Then, i describe how i got it working. Finally, i have some of my thoughts on why the simulation was failing at first.

## Initial attempt

I derived the analytical equations of the open chain system and simulated them successfully. I then added a constraint to close the chain. The constraint **is obeyed**, as it can be observed from the gif below.

[image: simulation gif]

**Important**: These gifs are not simulink simulation, but a visualization of the analytical equations. It was done like [that](https://www.mathworks.com/help/sm/ug/prescribe-joint-motion-in-four-bar-model.html)

### Mathematical modelling

1. I calculated the open chain dynamics with euler-lagrange equations. The results of the simulation (no actuation - free system) agree, see  "Open chain dynamics".
2. Then, i enforced the constraint:

$$ ^{W} P_{EE1} = \  ^{W} P_{EE2} $$

where $^{W}P_{EEi}$ is the position of the end effector with respect to the World Frame ${W}$  and indices 1,2 are the positions described by taking tranforms in each kinematic chain.

More details here:

> The kinematic chains are composed of the following links: (chain 1: {1-2-3}, chain 2: {1-4-5})
>
> The above positions were found by this:
>
> $$^{W}T_{EE1} = \ ^{W}T_{1}\ ^{1}T_{2}\ ^{2}T_{3}\ ^{3}T_{EE1}$$
>
> $$^{W}T_{EE2} = \ ^{W}T_{1}\ ^{1}T_{4}\ ^{4}T_{5}\ ^{5}T_{EE2}$$
> Taking the Position vector from a transform matrix was done: $P = T(1:3,4)$ (1 based indexing, matlab style).

So my constraint was:
$$ h(q) =\ ^{W} P_{EE1} - \  ^{W} P_{EE2}$$
And then, i differentiated twice. I got
$$H \dot{q} = 0 $$
$$ H \ddot{q} + \dot{H}\dot{q} = 0$$

- $H$ =  the jacobian of $h(q)$ with respect to $q$.
- $\dot{H} = \frac{\partial }{\partial t}  H$
- I calculated $H$ and $\dot{H}$ using the symbolic math toolbox from matlab.

I used the second constraint to solve for the constraint generalized forces. The dynamics of the system are:
$$ M(q) \ddot{q} + D \dot{q} + C(q,\dot{q}) \dot{q} + G(q) = \tau + H^T \lambda  $$
A shorthand is:
$$ M(q) \ddot{q} =  \tau_G + H^T \lambda   $$
So
$$ \lambda = - (H M^{-1}H^T)^{\dagger} (H M^{-1} \tau_G + \dot{H}\dot{q}) $$

- where $A^{\dagger}$ is the pseudo-inverse.

And then having $\lambda$, i return to the constrained euler-lagrange equation and solve the dynamics. This process is outlined [here](https://underactuated.csail.mit.edu/multibody.html#bilateral)

### Problem with this approach:

The closed chain dynamics seem defy physics.

1. The first joint rotates upward (and in the opposite direction from the simulink simulation).
2. The fixed point (figure below) **shouldn't be stable**. To find it, i added some damping $D = 0.005I$ in the simulation. (gravity is in $-z$). The simulation is below in "Damped simulation". The  system center of mass should be below the axis of rotation, and here it clearly isn't.

[image: unreasonable fixed point]

## How i got it working

### First change

I changed the constrained to be expressed in the Frame of the first link:

$$ h(q) =\ ^{1} P_{EE1} - \  ^{1} P_{EE2}$$

This improved the results. The leg was inward, and in the final configuration the torques from gravity were cancelling out. However, the leg was moved in the right. I knew this was wrong because the simulation was different from a damped simulink multibody simulation.

[image: leg in the right]

### Final change

I then noticed that:

$$ h(q) = \begin{bmatrix} h_1(q) \\ h_2(q) \\ \approx 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

- $\approx 0$ due to the presence of parameters like 1e-6 etc.

So, i kept only the first 2 constraints, and the **simulation worked correctly** (see figure below), with the presence of a small damping force ($0.005Nm/(rad/s)$).

- Without this damping, the simulation results do not match after 1s, but i suspect it has to do with the chaotic behaviour of this system.

[image]

That is explained, because in the link 1 frame, there can be differences only in the $x,y$ components.
[image]

## My thoughts

1. The second formulation failed, because there was a zero constraint which was differentiated. So, it was a numerical error in  my dynamics. Its contribution was small to drive the links apart and open then chain,  but it affected ever so slightly the system to make it go to the right.
2. Also, the gravity was right, because $q_1$ was not in $h(q)$, and thus the constraint force was not affecting link1.
3. The first formulation failed because it projected the above 2 constraints in to 3 constraints in the world frame. I do not know if $h(q)$ should have linear independent constraints, or the problem came from the pseudo-inverse though.

Some pointers on why it failed at first and how i can detect these wrong formulations in the feature are highly appreciated.

## Extra

### Open chain dynamics results

[image: comparison of states- open chain]

### Damped simulation

The damped simulation is below:

[image]